# Парсинг открытой информации на сайте Росреестра

Tags: python, парсер, requests, росреестр

Пишу скрипт на Python с использованием библиотеки requests для парсинга данный с сайта Росреестра.
Если точнее парсинг вот этой формы: [Справочная информация по объектам недвижимости в режиме online](https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_portal_services/online_request)

Я начал с конца, отдельные [страницы](https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_portal_services/online_request/!ut/p/c5/hY3LDoIwFAW_yNxbaSkumxJokSKCidANQUMICQ8XxoS_F3TjRj1nOZkMWFg-1o-ure_dNNY9FGDdijEj9T4k6KWBh3rHODUqIdR3F166lQ6jVK08PMaIWvo5SQVHTPGPHYFt--mydM5r2a2QMEEURX0wDkMh5CkyPNuiR9_8V-nlf5lASNQ0NFCC5Z8VKVHITIk4Ng4KAmXftPV1httQzLneBE8lW46n/dl3/d3/L0lJSklna21BL0lKakFBQ3lBQkVSQ0pBISEvNEZHZ3NvMFZ2emE5SUFnIS83XzAxNUExSDQwSU9NQ0MwQUNSSEFMTE0zMEExL1h2aWhUOTc4MDIwNQ!!/?PC_7_015A1H40IOMCC0ACRHALLM30A1000000_ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.handler.BeanNameParameterHandlerMapping-PATH=%2FObjectDataController&object_data_id=77:1:1001:1020) парсятся нормально.

Застрял на начальной форме.
Как передать запрос с указанием адреса в [начальную](https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_portal_services/online_request) форму, например такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не смотрели api росрестра? Все же удобнее получать данные без парсинга html и отправки формы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сейчас есть REST интерфейс для подобных запросов - описание доступно в [doc-файле](https://rosreestr.ru/wps/PA_FCCLPGUMWPSPtalApp/ru.fccland.pgu.infoblock?param_infoblock_file_path=doc/doc_rest_online_2.doc&param_infoblock_name=cc_ib_open_data&ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceServlet.directRequest=x&ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.handler.BeanNameParameterHandlerMapping-PATH=/FileDownloaderController).

---

Описание REST-ресурсов сервиса
«Онлайн-Справка» версии 0.0.2

1. Для получение региональной информации необходимо воспользоваться следующими методами:

   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/macro_regions` – ресурс используется для получения списка макро-регионов.
   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/regions/{parent-id}` – ресурс используется для получения дочерних регионов по идентификатору родителя.
     Пример использования:
     `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/regions/104201000000`
   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/region_types/{parent-id}` - список типов дочерних         регионов.
     Пример использования:
     `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/region_types/104201000000`
2. Для получении информации о земельном участке или объекте недвижимости по идентификатору, необходимо воспользоваться методом:

   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_object/{object-id}` – где вместо {object-id}  необходимо подставить идентификатор объекта.
     Пример использования:
     `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_object/2:56:30302:639`
3. Для поиска объекта недвижимости создано 3  ресурса — поиск по номеру (кадастровому, условному, устаревшему, номеру права и ограничения), отдельный ресурс по номеру права/ограничения  и по адресу.

   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_objects/{number}` – поиск по номеру объекта.
     Пример:
     `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_objects/2:56:30302:639`

     Результатом поиска будет 0 или множество (не больше 200) объектов,  удовлетворяющих маске номера.
   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/right/{region}/{number}` – поиск по номеру объекта, где {region} – цифровой код региона и {number} – номер права/ограничения
     Пример:
     `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/right/177/50-50-21%2F042%2F2012-234`

     Результатом поиска будет 0 или 1 объект, номер права или ограничения которого совпал с указанным номером
   - `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects` - URL для поиска объектов    недвижимости методом POST.
     Список передаваемых полей (long - число в виде строки, String произвольная строка):

     ```
     long macroRegionId    - id макрорегиона
     long regionId         - id региона
     long settlementId     - id населенного пункта

     String settlementType - тип населенного пункта (необязательное поле, используется для   фильтрации списка населенных пунктов от типа)
     String streetType     - тип улицы (необятельное поле)   
     String street         - наименование улицы
     String house          - номер дома
     String apartment      - номер квартиры
     String building      - номер корпуса
     String structure     - номер строения
     ```

     Список возможных значений поля streetType:

     ```
     str1=Улица
     str2=Переулок
     str3=Проспект
     str4=Площадь
     str5=Микрорайон
     str6=Аллея
     str7=Бульвар
     str8=Аал
     str9=Аул
     str10=Въезд
     str11=Выселки
     str12=Городок
     str13=Деревня
     str14=Дорога
     str15=ж/д остановочный (обгонный) пункт
     str16=Железнодорожная будка
     str17=Железнодорожная казарма
     str18=Железнодорожная платформа
     str19=Железнодорожная станция
     str20=Железнодорожный пост
     str21=Железнодорожный разъезд
     str22=Животноводческая точка
     str23=Заезд
     str24=Казарма
     str25=Квартал
     str26=Километр
     str27=Кольцо
     str28=Линия
     str29=Местечко
     str30=Набережная
     str31=Населенный пункт
     str32=Остров
     str33=Парк
     str34=Переезд
     str35=Планировочный район
     str36=Платформа
     str37=Площадка
     str38=Полустанок
     str39=Поселок/станция
     str40=Поселок сельского типа
     str41=Починок
     str42=Почтовое отделение
     str43=Проезд
     str44=Просек
     str45=Проселок
     str46=Проулок
     str47=Разъезд
     str48=Сад
     str49=Село
     str50=Сквер
     str51=Слобода
     str52=Станция
     str53=Строение
     str54=Территория
     str55=Тракт
     str56=Тупик
     str57=Участок
     str58=Хутор
     str59=Шоссе
     ```

Answer (score 3):

Правильный запрос к форме такой:

```
URL  = ur'https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_portal_services/online_request/!ut/p/c5/hY3LCsIwFAW_SO6N5lGXIcUm0dRoBdtsQgUphT5ciODf2-paPWc5DAMBpg_1o23qezsOdQclBB4Zc8psM4KJ3yRo1kxQp3NCUz7xikeTWa9nnh12iEalBfFSIHr8Y1sITTdeps55LvOIhEmiKZq9WzGUUp2sE8clJvTDf5Xe_pdJhFyP_RVuffkszEK-AJ5kER8!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSWdrbUEhIS9JRFJBQUlpQ2dBek15cXchLzRCRWo4bzBGbEdpdC1iWHBBRUEhLzdfMDE1QTFINDBJT01DQzBBQ1JIQUxMTTMwQTEvQmZSdTMyNjA5MDEyOQ!!/?PC_7_015A1H40IOMCC0ACRHALLM30A1000000_ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.handler.BeanNameParameterHandlerMapping-PATH=%2fSearchAction'`

payload = {
    "search_action":    "true",
    "subject":          "",
    "region":           "",
    "settlement":       "",
    "cad_num":          "",
    "start_position":   "",
    "obj_num":          "",
    "old_number":       "",
    "search_type":      "ADDRESS",
    "src_object":       "0",
    "subject_id":       "145000000000",
    "region_id":        "-1",
    "street_type":      "str0",
    "street":           "кремль",
    "house":            "",
    "building":         "",
    "structure":        "",
    "apartment":        "",
    "r_subject_id":     "101000000000",
    "right_reg":        "",
    "encumbrance_reg":  ""
}

requests.post(URL, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 2):

Узнайте тип передачи данных.
Если в теге form атрибут method равен get, значит тип будет get, то же самое с post.

Почитайте тут: http://www.myfirstsite.ru/articles/get-and-post

А еще посмотрите вот сюда: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!